ScrollReveal text disappears when I insert meta desc and title
I have a PHP website. All important meta tags are in the navbar.php which I include on every page. When I insert a meta description and a title for the individual pages, the texts that I have animated with ScrollReveal disappear. The text disappears immediately if a title or a meta tag is inserted on the page. In Navbar.php a no title. Since I need a single title on each page because of the SEO optimization

<?php include 'navbar.php' ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navbar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/contact.css">

<title>Haarmacherei</title>
<meta name="description" content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab possimus eius nisi dolorem. Impedit modi ea velit vitae dolorum, asperiores facilis incidunt veniam nesciunt, recusandae eaque explicabo illo doloremque veritatis, sequi quae distinctio laudantium fugiat odit quisquam error voluptate accusantium quam? Reprehenderit sint eveniet incidunt qui, consequatur iure veniam? Harum dolorum suscipit aspernatur ipsam nihil hic dolor dignissimos perferendis facere.">

<?php include 'imageSlider.php' ?>

<?php include 'fixed-icons.php' ?>


<!--Reveal Scroll-->
<script>
    //h1
    ScrollReveal({
        distance: "400px",
        easing: "ease-in"
    });
    ScrollReveal().reveal(".landing-h1", {
        delay: 300,
        origin: "left",
    });

    //p
    ScrollReveal({
        distance: "400px",
        easing: "ease-in"
    });
    ScrollReveal().reveal(".landing-btns", {
        delay: 500,
        origin: "left",
    });

    //btns
    ScrollReveal({
        distance: "400px",
        easing: "ease-in"
    });
    ScrollReveal().reveal(".landing-text", {
        delay: 400,
        origin: "left",
    });
</script>


<div class="landing-hook">
    <div class="content">
        Gib jedem Tag die Chance, <br> der Schönste deines Lebens zu werden.
    </div>
</div>

<section id="welcomePage">
    <div class="welcome-container">
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="img/shutterStock/indexAboutUs.jpeg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="welcome-content">
            <h2 class="welcome-content-heading">Aus Leidenschaft für Ihre Schönheit.</h2>
            <p class="welcome-content-p">Seit 2020 begeistern wir unsere Kunden mit einem Mix aus Lifestyle und authentischen Persönlichkeiten in Burgoberbach. Wir bieten professionelle Premium Dienstleistungen in den Bereich Pflege und Haarstyling an.
                Schönheit und Wohlbefinden ist unsere Philosophie.

                Ob Farbe, Balayage, verschiedene Strähnentechniken, Schnitt, Strukturglättung, Hochsteckfrisuren für Ihren besonderen Tag - die Individualität eines jeden Kunden steht im Mittelpunkt - passende, charakteristische Looks, welche die eigene Schönheit der Menschen zum Strahlen bringt. So ist es der Anspruch eines jeden Teammitglieds, den Besuch im Zeitlos zum Erlebnis und zum Highlight der Gäste zu machen.

                Wir legen viel Wert auf Qualität, Kundenbindung, Wohlfühlatmosphäre und gute Gespräche!

            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!--Reveal Scroll-->
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    ScrollReveal().reveal(".welcome-content", {
        delay: 500,
        origin: "left",
    });
  });
</script>




As this will most likely be a client-side issue, do you have an example of the source code being generated, instead of your php code?
